# Show posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I'm a newbie on WordPress and ar trying to do a change on a site.

Now the site shows unlimited of posts and articles. I want to change this to only show 5 articles and posts together.

I don't reallt know how to change it since this also is connected to the button. This button shall still show all post and articles when you click on it.

Do any one have a clue how I can move forward with this?

Best regards,

```html
<?php get_header();?>

 <?php get_template_part( 'templates/top', 'section' ); ?>

 <section class="blog-section">

  <div class="row">

   <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>
 
      <main id="main" class="blog-section__main small-12 large-8 medium-6 small-order-1 medium-order-2 columns" role="main">
      
    <div class="news-feed">
     <h2 class="news-feed__heading h3"><?php echo __('Articles and blog posts'); ?></h2>
        <?php
        
        // Fetch news posts
        $posts = get_news_posts([
         'posts_per_page' => NEWS_POSTS_PER_PAGE
        ]);

        if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();

      get_template_part( 'templates/loop', 'news' );
         
     endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    if( $posts->found_posts > $posts->post_count )
     echo '<a href="#" data-offset="' .  NEWS_POSTS_PER_PAGE . '" id="load-more-news" class="button button--primary"> <div class="news-button">' . __('Load more') . '</div> </button>'
    ?>

<!--      <?php page_navi(); ?> -->
     
    <?php else : ?>
           
     <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'missing' ); ?>
      
    <?php endif; ?>
                        
      </main> <!-- end #main -->

  </div> <!-- end .row -->

 </section> <!-- end .blog -->

 <?php 
  
  global $post;

  $qo = get_queried_object();

  $post->ID = $qo->ID;

  get_template_part('templates/flexible-content'); 

 ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `posts_per_page` argument sets how many posts to return. In your code, this is set to the constant `NEWS_POSTS_PER_PAGE`:

```
$posts = get_news_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => NEWS_POSTS_PER_PAGE
]);
```

`get_news_posts` isn't a native WP function so I assume its either in a custom theme or plugin you are using, and presumably the theme / plugin has a setting to change the value of `NEWS_POSTS_PER_PAGE` so you really shouldn't be changing the code.

The correct way to change this would be to find and change that setting so that is applied across every usage of the plugin. However if you *really* need to do this in the code, you would set a different value for posts_per_page, e.g.

```
$posts = get_news_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => 5
]);
```

**However directly changing the code could cause other issues, and if it is not your own theme then the change WILL be overwritten when you update it, so please look for the setting in the theme or plugins first!**

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand. I will look for the setting in the theme or check if there is a plugin used.

Comment: @Erhan Glad to hear it :) But at least now you know where the value is being set if you do have to take the drastic action of changing the code yourself.